# GCP roles replacement for roles/editor which doesn't have `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs` permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, identity-management

The reason for looking into this is because editor role has `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs` permission which could allow the users to potentially interact/change things outside of the folder if they can find a service account with enough privilege.

To get around this issue, we are thinking of replacing editor role with bunch of roles per GCP product, so that the user still have similar access on resources inside this project, but without being able to act as a service account.

Does anyone knows of an easier way of doing it rather than going and comparing each product roles' permissions with editor role permissions manually?

Comment: Comparing IAM roles for each resource is exactly what you should do. There are few shortcuts to good security. Knowing the permissions that you are trying to manage is one of the first steps.

Answer (score 2):

As @ johnhanley said Comparing IAM roles for each resource is exactly what you should do.

You can view who has access to your project, folder, or organization using the Google Cloud console, the gcloud CLI, the REST API, or the Resource Manager client libraries.

By using google cloud console:

1. Go to [IAM](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/iam-admin/) Page
2. Select required  project, folder, or organization which you want to edit policy
3. After selecting you can view permissions of project by 2 filters i.e., by permissions and by roles as shown in the below image.

[image]
By using view by roles you can easily find out the permissions which you have granted and replace them accordingly as per your requirement.